# Erro ao importar arquivos .csv

Tags: r

Recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Cannot change working driectory?

Essa mensagem esta sempre aparecendo quando eu tento inserir no meu console o arquivo `csv`.

```
diretorio <-"C:/Users/Leonardo Bergamo/Desktop/notasMac113.csv"

setwd(diretorio)

planilha<-read.csv(notasMac113.csv)

print(notasMac113.csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer dessa forma:

`setwd("C:/Users/Leonardo Bergamo/Desktop")`

`planilha = read.csv("notasMac113.csv", header = TRUE)
 print(planilha)`

Você também pode consultar este [código](https://repl.it/@maatheusgois/Read-csv) para mais detalhes.